# Evaluate: $I = \int^{\pi/2}_0 (\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x})^{-4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

**Evaluate :** $$I = \int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2} (\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x})^{-4}\ dx$$

**Attempt :**
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2} (\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x})^{-4}\ dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2} \left( \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}-\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sin x - \cos x}\right)^{4}\ dx
\end{align}

Is it the right way to proceed it? Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2} (\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x})^{-4}\ dx&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac1{(\sqrt{\cos x})^4\ (1+\sqrt{\tan x})^4}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\sec^2x}{(1+\sqrt{\tan x})^4}\ dx\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[1]}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{(1+\sqrt{u})^4}\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[2]}}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{t}{(1+t)^4}\ dt\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[3]}}=2\cdot\text{B}(2,2)\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac13}.
\end{align}

---

**Notes :**

$\color{red}{[1]}\;\;\;u=\tan x$

$\color{red}{[2]}\;\;\;t=\sqrt{u}$

$\color{red}{[3]}\;\;\;$[Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) : $\displaystyle\text{B}(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}\ dt$ for $\Re(x)>0$ and $\Re(y)>0$

Comment: +1 for a very nice answer, but I just wanted to point out for the readers who may be afraid of advanced topics like the Beta function can certainly avoid it by using the fact that $\frac{t}{(1+t)^4}=\frac{1}{(1+t)^3}-\frac{1}{(1+t)^4}$ after the fourth line instead.

Comment: Setting $\tan x=t^2$ will be a shortcut.

Comment: do you think this could be generalized to $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}\right)^{-n}dx?$$